# How to get the actual URL in php?

Tags: php

I have the url 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/entities/zip_codes/AL_36574/9t/ej/3z/

when you go to this url it go to 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=AL+36574
here.

Now i want this url from the previous one.
therefore i created the code like this

```
<?php
$url="http://www.wolframalpha.com/entities/zip_codes/AL_36574/9t/ej/3z/";
    $headers = get_headers($url, 1);



// will echo http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=AL+36574
echo $headers[0];
?>
```

but it does not works Plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curl would be the best way to find out the redirect. I had this code for my own purposes a while ago, it is not my own. You will have to work out the regex yourself.

```
<?php
$url="http://www.wolframalpha.com/entities/zip_codes/AL_36574/9t/ej/3z/";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); // We'll parse redirect url from header.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE); // We want to just get redirect url but not to follow it.
$response = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all('^0;url=\'(.*?)[$\']+^', $response, $matches);
curl_close($ch);
echo !empty($matches[1]) ? "http://www.wolframalpha.com".trim($matches[1][0]) : 'No redirect found';
?>
```

You can see it working here http://viper-7.com/TPqpJ8

Comment: Ok, I added the regex for you then, the idea was for you to create the regex. 

This will give you the "/input/?i=AL+36574" part of the url, please accept my answer.

Comment: Added full domain for you in there now.

Answer (score 2):

You have to parse `Location` from headers and not just output 1st header (HTTP Response Code).

```
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
echo $headers['Location'];
```

Notice how your page returns a 404 response and then redirects using a meta refresh. Reading headers via PHP for this case won't work. PHP can not ordinarily read JavaScript or html redirects that occur after the page has been generated already, Unless you want to try parsing DOM

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='/input/?i=AL+36574' " />
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: Location

Comment: That simply means your url is not setting a redirect header and is using either an HTML or Javascript redirect. Hence your method won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?

something like this :

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
{
    $a=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    echo "Your previous page URL is ".$a;
}
```